# Isomorphic fetch and Django view

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I'm sending a POST request to Django view using isomorphic fetch.

```
body : "{"email":"admin@example.com","password":"11"}"
credentials : "same-origin"
headers :

Accept : "application/json"
Content-Type : "application/json"
X-CSRFToken : "mudIfipiyLUao2ZWwoEotFOUknYeVpZASNpQQ2IdadRVOe0a9n5tUqcKzwtrDuWX"
method : "POST"
```

When I send this request to DRF view, I can read the data using `request.data`. However when I send the same data to Django view, request.POST is empty.

What could be the reason?

Comment: Please show the actual code you are using in the client and the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that isomorphic fetch is probably not playing a critical role in why `request.POST` is empty but rather that `request.POST` only seems to be populated by form data, not JSON data. This is supported by this quote from the [Django REST Framework](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/) docs:

> It (request.data) supports REST framework's flexible request parsing, rather than just supporting form data

Also, note the advice from Malcom Tredinnick:

> If you're doing REST-based web service stuff ... you should ignore request.POST

This is in reference to the fact that DRF handles a lot of stuff behind the scenes for you such as serializing things and assigning to different variables and by inter-operating with the pure Django equivalents you may get weird results.